# How can I view the sum/average velocity over all timesteps in Paraview?

Tags: csv, point-clouds, paraview, post-processing

I imported a point cloud (with velocity, pressure, ...) into Paraview.

What I found so far: a temporal statistics filter that calculates the average of all points per time step.

What I am looking for: a filter that calculates the average of all time steps per particle.

I could write the data into a csv file and load it back into Paraview for visualization. But is there an easier way of doing it directly in Paraview?

Answer (score 1):

Want you want is the 'Temporal Statistics' filter.

Be aware that you cannot choose a specific array to compute: it will process all available arrays.